# IOS: stop a generic thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsthread

In my app I use this code to start a NSThread

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStart) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


- (void)threadStart 
{  
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

//something to do...

[pool release];
}
```

my problem is that I want start and stop this thread sometimes, then I have to declare a thread in .h, to have a generic thread...is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to stop your thread executing is to ask it nicely to stop executing. Then, in your thread, you listen for such requests and obey them at an appropriate time.

According to [Apple's Thread Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html):

> Although Cocoa, POSIX, and Multiprocessing Services offer routines for killing threads directly, the use of such routines is strongly discouraged. Killing a thread prevents that thread from cleaning up after itself. Memory allocated by the thread could potentially be leaked and any other resources currently in use by the thread might not be cleaned up properly, creating potential problems later.
>
> If you anticipate the need to terminate a thread in the middle of an operation, you should design your threads from the outset to respond to a cancel or exit message. For long-running operations, this might mean stopping work periodically and checking to see if such a message arrived. If a message does come in asking the thread to exit, the thread would then have the opportunity to perform any needed cleanup and exit gracefully; otherwise, it could simply go back to work and process the next chunk of data.

You could either use `[NSThread exit];` in your thread to stop itself i.e. to cancel the current thread,

or you can also use `[NSThread cancel]` [method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to signal ***another*** thread in your program to cancel..

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking. Threads cannot be stopped from another thread (safely). There are several approaches to do work on a background thread and to manage other threads lifetime.

You should describe what you're trying to accomplish. Why do you want to stop the background thread? Is there sometimes no work to be done?